# drawing diagonals in every div of specific class?

Tags: javascript, drawing

Generally speaking - is it possible to draw with javascript two diagonal lines inside of a specific div on a website? It should basically look like a placeholder image … e.g. http://wightwildflowers.com/assets/images/placeholder.png

I'm just curious. If it's possible how would it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it reasonable to dynamically add and size the placeholder image you just showed? That might be your best bet.

You could also try working with the `canvas` element.

Answer (score 1):

You could add  tags for each specific div with the correct size to your DOM and link the image.  It will be a bit distorted.

OTO you can also try to create a canvas over each such div and draw the lines there.

Answer (score 1):

there isn't a good native way to do this. the only pure javascript solution is to build a 2d array of some html element (table cells or divs or whatever) and treat them as pixels, coloring specific cells.

providing/generating an image is probably a good alternative.

the next option is using something like [raphaeljs](http://raphaeljs.com) to generate browser supported vector images. this should work fairly reliably but adds a lot of weight to your page to draw two lines.